# storing plots in pdf which I was able to store earlier but not anymore with some modifications in code

Tags: r

below is the code that invokes a user-defined function name meanValPlot.
I am able to get the graphic output on sole but if I try to save the same into pdf, it's not working. I believe I am missing out something very minute but appreciate if you could help.

Thanks in advance.

```
library(raster)
library(splines)

#function definition
meanValPlot<-function(input,disp=1, xlims=c(1,24), 
               product='test model', upDir=getwd(), 
               lineCols='orange', ylims=c(0,1)){ 
    counter<-dim(input)[2] 
 # specifies the number of models we have for particular variable

dev.new(width=3.33,height=3.0)
#pdf(file='test1march.pdf',width=3.33,height=3.0)

par(mar=c(2.5,3,1,1))
plot(NULL,NULL,xlim=xlims,ylim=ylims,axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)     

    axis(1, at=c(0,4,8,12,16,20,24),cex.axis=0.7,mgp=c(3, .3, 0))
    axis(2, las=1,cex.axis=0.7,at=c(-2,-1,0,1,2), mgp=c(3, .7, 0))
mtext(side = 1, text =expression('Hour'), line = 1,font=15)
mtext(side = 2, text = expression(paste('NEE  ', m^-2,s^-1)), line = 1.5,font=15)

sapply(1:counter,function(x){ 
xa<-1:24 
yy<-predict(interpSpline(xa,input[,x]))
lines(yy,col=lineCols[x],type="l", pch=22, lty=1, lwd=1)
})

    box()
#dev.off()
par(mar=c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1)

}#end meanValPlot


#setting the array values
NEE_values<-mat.or.vec(24,2)

NEE_values[,1]<-c(0.0188026316,0.0185296053,0.0181710526,0.0169046053,0.0140860927,0.0101523179,0.0051907895,0.0005065359,-0.0034477124,-0.0065620915,-0.0092810458, -0.0118823529,-0.0138267974, -0.0154084967, -0.0163039216,-0.0155261438, -0.0145522876, -0.0108921569,-0.0045164474,0.0018388158, 0.0083453947, 0.0136710526,
0.0170065789,0.0184342105)

NEE_values[,2]<-c(0.85902632, 0.90200329,0.91822697, 0.85789145,0.73128808,0.52779470, 0.20285855,-0.12150654,-0.45393464,-0.82072876,-1.08471242,-1.32177124,
-1.38211765,-1.39515033,-1.38801961,-1.31286601,-1.22851307,-1.03020588,-0.72745066,-0.39643750, 0.02863816,0.37534539,0.60530921, 0.79088816)

#invoking function here
ylims<-c(-2,2)
lineCols <- c('blue','black') 
meanValPlot(input=NEE_values,product='NEE Site data',upDir=outpath, lineCols=lineCols, ylims=ylims)
```

Comment: You have not provided xlims and ylims  (or 'input' for that matter) so that code throws errors.

Comment: I have defined these values: xlims<-c(1,24) and ylims<-c(-2,2). As I said, the first version is working well. The more customized one is able to plot figures on output console if I remove the pdf() and dev.off() command. Please help me with the same.

Comment: Please make your example reproducible, so I can paste it into my console and it runs. For example, add `library(splines)` so I won't get the error `could not find function "interpSpline"`.

Comment: Hi bdemarest and Others, I have posted a reproducible code, please have a look at it.

Comment: I ran it and I get a plot. I say again, you need to post details about your version of R, your versions of the packages, and about your machine!

Comment: Your code also works for me. When I uncomment the `pdf` and `dev.off` lines, and comment out the `dev.new` line, I get a pdf file identical to the interactive plot.

Comment: Hi, I restarted everything and run it few times. It is showing the output in pdf using ur suggested syntax. 
Sorry for the trouble caused but thanks for the tip. I am using R version 2.12.2 (2011-02-25)

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to drop the first line with `dev.new()` and use the `pdf` call to create the proper sized image:

```
xlims<-c(1,24)
ylims<-c(-2,2)

pdf(file='test1march.pdf', width=3.33,height=4)
plot(NULL,NULL,xlim=xlims,ylim=ylims,axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)     
axis(1, at=c(0,4,8,12,16,20,24),cex.axis=0.7,mgp=c(3, .3, 0))
axis(2, las=1,cex.axis=0.7,at=c(-2,-1,0,1,2), mgp=c(3, .7, 0))
mtext(side = 1, text =expression('Hour'), line = 1,font=15)
mtext(side = 2, text = expression(paste('NEE ', m^-2,s^-1)), line = 1.5,font=15)
abline(0, 2/24)  # should give a diagonal line
box()
dev.off()
```

[image]

Your current code will be accepting the default for the PDF dimensions. You *do* need to keep the dev.off(). That's the only way you can finish the file.

Comment: Hi, I tried but same issue persists. Pdf is created but does not have anything in it and its not opening while R interface is on.

Comment: You will not see anything in the R console to indicate success. The only way to assess file output is to look in your working directory for the file. (And 'doesn't have anything in it' means no axes or box?)

Comment: hi, yes the output pdf is blank 1 page document.

Comment: Try restarting a fresh session. You could have some other package messing with your settings as I did earlier today. Then, if you have run the code above with no modifications and it still creates a blank plot, you will need to post more information about your machine and version of R.